# Missing distances when using igraph shortest distance

Tags: python, networkx, igraph, osmnx

I am trying to calculate the distance between the nodes of my network and two sources. Afterwards I the save the shortest distance in a list (called `route_length`). However **my network has `9693` nodes** and **after running my code and calculating the shortest paths I only have
`9602` distances**. I don't understand why I have less distances than nodes, plus if in the loop I save the nodes in a list and print it's length at the end it too gives me a result of 9602 nodes, which is not correct.

**Here is my code:**

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
import pandas as pd
from shapely.wkt import loads as load_wkt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import igraph as ig
import matplotlib as mpl
import random as rd
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)


city = 'Portugal, Lisbon'
G = ox.graph_from_place(city, network_type='drive')

G_nx = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)

ox.speed.add_edge_speeds(G_nx, hwy_speeds=20, fallback=20)

ox.speed.add_edge_travel_times(G_nx)

weight = 'travel_time'

coord_1 = (38.74817825481225, -9.160815118526642)  # Coordenada Hospital Santa Maria
coord_2 = (38.74110711410615, -9.152159572392323)  # Coordenada Hopstial Curry Cabral
coord_3 = (38.7287248180068, -9.139114834357233) # Hospital Dona Estefania
coord_4 = (38.71814053423293, -9.137885476529883) # Hospital Sao Jose 
target_1 = ox.get_nearest_node(G_nx, coord_1)
target_2 = ox.get_nearest_node(G_nx, coord_2)
target_3 = ox.get_nearest_node(G_nx, coord_3)
target_4 = ox.get_nearest_node(G_nx, coord_4)


G_ig = ig.Graph(directed=True)
G_ig.add_vertices(list(G_nx.nodes()))
G_ig.add_edges(list(G_nx.edges()))
G_ig.vs['osmid'] = list(nx.get_node_attributes(G_nx, 'osmid').values())
G_ig.es[weight] = list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G_nx, weight).values())

assert len(G_nx.nodes()) == G_ig.vcount()
assert len(G_nx.edges()) == G_ig.ecount()

route_length=[]
list_nodes=[]

for node in G_nx.nodes:
    length_1 = G_ig.shortest_paths(source=node, target=target_1, weights=weight)[0][0]
    length_2 = G_ig.shortest_paths(source=node, target=target_2, weights=weight)[0][0]

    if length_1<length_2:
       route_length.append(length_1)
       list_nodes.append(node)

   elif length_2 < length_1:
       route_length.append(length_2)
       list_nodes.append(node)

print(len(route_length))
print(len(list_nodes))
```

If the nodes are disconnected the shortest path should be `inf`. And I don't have any inf values in the `route_length` list.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first thing that popped into my mind was what about the case when length_1 == length_2? Is that the condition that is satisfied (and hence not accounted for by the if and life and not appended in the list route_length) for the missing 91 cases?

Comment: Is len(list_nodes) = 9602 as well?

Comment: Yeah len(list_nodes) is also 9602. I ended up removing the 2nd condition and replaced it with an "else". You're right! My conditions removed the possibility of the lengths being the same. I forgot about that because they can  only the same when the node are disconnected. This means the length would be inf. The lengths can only be the same in this circumstance because the network is directional.

Comment: You can create an answer with the same content of your comment and I'll check it as the correct answer so you can have the rep points.

Comment: Okay. I will do that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that popped into my mind was what about the case when 
`length_1 == length_2`?

I believe that is the condition that is satisfied (and hence not accounted for by the `if` and `elif` and not appended in the list `route_length` and list `list_nodes`) for the missing 91 cases.